# RDLC with Object as DataSource

Tags: c#, winforms, reportviewer, objectdatasource

m trying to display a rdlc report from my class object

here is the class

```
public class BillInfo
{
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public String Date { get; set; }
    public String splInstructions { get; set; }
    public List<OrderItem> oItems { get; set; }
    public String GrossTotal { get; set; }
    public String DiscountAmount { get; set; }
    public String NetTotal { get; set; }
}

public class OrderItem
{
    public OrderItem() { }
    public OrderItem(String sNo, String Qty, String Amt, String ttl) 
    {
        this.SNo = sNo;
        this.Quantity = Qty;
        this.Amount = Amt;
        this.Total = ttl;
    }

    public String SNo { get; set; }
    public String Quantity { get; set; }
    public String Amount { get; set; }
    public String Total { get; set; }
}
```

now i add the datasource object of class **BillInfo** in the datasource window
and added a report viewer, now when i try to add datasource vaue as the object of bill info class it gives me this strange error

```
this.BillDataViewer.LocalReport.ReportPath = "C:/Users/Guest1/Desktop/Billinator/Billinator/MainReport.rdlc";
this.BillDataViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("BillInfo", MainForm.GetBillData()));
this.BillDataViewer.RefreshReport();
```

the second line where i add the datasource is giving me this error

```
Value does not fall within the expected range.
```

"   at Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource.set_Value(Object value)\r\n   at Billinator.ReportViewer.ReportViewer_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\Guest1\Desktop\Billinator\Billinator\ReportViewer.cs:line 23\r\n   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnLoad(EventArgs e)\r\n   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)\r\n   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl()\r\n   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmShowWindow(Message& m)\r\n   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)\r\n   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)\r\n   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)"

Please suggest where am i going wrong

Comment: What type does `MainForm.GetBillData()` return?  Can you post the code for that method?